# asp.net postback data

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, postback

I have a page with a dynamic table, data pulled from a GET method.

On it, a button which POSTs to another asp page.

Once you click the button, if everything went fine, the table should should be emtpy but even though the POST occurs successfully, after the postback caused by the button click, the table still has data even though it should not.

If the page is refreshed only then does it update.

How to make it so it updates after the button click? (there may be a slight delay after the POST and getting the data hence it still shows the content of the table).

Comment: the code is waaay too long to put in here. maybe i need to sleep it a second or two, to give the GEt method to pull the updated data?

Comment: Don't think we're understanding what you trying to do. Yeah give it sometime, that usually helps. Sounds like a design problem.

Comment: there is also a timer which costantly does postback regardless of events

Comment: How is the data actually fetched in the first place? Is it contained in the URL (as a GET-param?), or does the GET-param specify where the data should be fetched from? Postback might simply be saving the data you have as part of the viewstate, and not reloading it the way you want upon postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not the case of "double page load" and initialization?

```
   if(!isPostBack)
   {
        //Clear Table
   }
```

Comment: Well on post back it always needs to get the data from GET http method so it should auto-update, but i think because it does the POST, then the postback right after, it doesn't get a chance to pull it so quickly?

Comment: So Page A posts to Page B to update information in a Table. When Page B is done, Page A should now display the new result. If I'm not understanding, can you elaborate or post some code.

Comment: Ok if I give it 3 seconds to wait, it seems to work as intended.

Comment: ..but the problem is only related to Page A, right? The post to B works fine, but the content in A is not updated? Ie., the data fetched (somehow depening on GET-parameters) is not fetched anew, so page A becomes outdated? Waiting three seconds does not sound like an ideal solution. Maybe you can force the GET-data to be reloaded upon postback instead?

Comment: It is forced, but the POST is not instant and it pulls back the data before the POST had a change to fully commit I believe. Hence the wait works

Comment: Yes because it's a cross POST and the most expensive part is "opening connection and modifying data", your POSTBACK on Page A will always finish first. SignalR would be great for this to give you a status message when POST is fully committed. That way Page A will only update when notified. 3 seconds may not always work if Website is internet facing.